# How to configure karma.conf.js to run tests in Angular - Electron application?

Tags: angular, typescript, electron, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to configure karma to run tests for Electron (nodejs) and Angular code. This configuration works only for Angular ( `ng test` ) part of code but completely doesnt work for Electron part. I run test using script in package.json file which looks like that:

```
"electron:test": "karma start karma.conf.js"
```

this script throws an exception:

```
Server start failed on port 9876: Error: The '@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma' karma plugin is meant to be used from within Angular CLI and will not work correctly outside of it
```

my karma.conf.js:

```
module.exports = function (config) {
 config.set({
  basePath: '',
  frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
  files: [
  // Angular files
  'app_angular/src/**/*.ts',
  'app_angular/src/**/*.spec.ts',

  // Electron files
  'app_electron/src/**/*.ts',
  'app_electron/test/**/*.spec.ts'
],
plugins: [
  require('karma-jasmine'),
  require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
  require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
  require('karma-coverage'),
  require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
],
client: {
  jasmine: {
    // you can add configuration options for Jasmine here
    // the possible options are listed at https://jasmine.github.io/api/edge/Configuration.html
    // for example, you can disable the random execution with `random: false`
    // or set a specific seed with `seed: 4321`
  },
  clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
},
jasmineHtmlReporter: {
  suppressAll: true // removes the duplicated traces
},
coverageReporter: {
  dir: require('path').join(__dirname, './coverage/app'),
  subdir: '.',
  reporters: [
    { type: 'html', subdir: 'html-report' },
    { type: 'text-summary' },
    { type: 'lcov', subdir: 'lcov-report' }
  ]
},
reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
port: 9876,
colors: true,
logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
autoWatch: true,
browsers: ['ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox'],
singleRun: false,
restartOnFileChange: true,
customLaunchers: {
  ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox: {
    base: 'ChromeHeadless',
    flags: [
      '--no-sandbox'
    ]
  }
}
```

});
};

Comment: angular version: 16, electron version: 27